# If $H\cap K=e$ then $H$ and $K$ are normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

For $|G|=p^km$ for $p$ is prime and $p$ does not divide $m$. Let $H=[x\in G \mid x^{p^k}=e]$ for $H<G$ and let $K=[x\mid x^m=e] $ for $K<G$. We are not assuming G is abelian

Show that $H\cap K=\{e\}.$ Then show $H$ and $K$ are normal.

Note that $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $K$. Hence, by Lagrange's theorem, the size of $H\cap K$ divides $p^k$ and m. $(p^k,m)=1$ thus $H\cap K=\{e\}$

Then how does this mean that H and K are normal?

Comment: Something must be missing here since this would mean there don't exist (non-trivial) simple groups...but there are!

Comment: Well, usually, $H$ and $K$ are not subgroups; here, they're assumed to be subgroups?

Comment: yes they are. what do you think is missing?

Comment: Let $G=S_3$; then, for $p=2$, your $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I think the point is to assume they are subgroups.

Answer (score 5):

Note that, in general, $H$ and $K$ are not subgroups of $G$.

If you *assume* they are, then $H$ is a $p$-group and the order of any element in $K$ divides $m$. Since no power of $p$ divides $m$, an element in $H\cap K$ must have order $1$.

Recall that $(xyx^{-1})^r=xy^rx^{-1}$.

> If $h\in H$ and $g\in G$, then you have $h^{p^k}=1$ for some $k$ and so$$(ghg^{-1})^{p^k}=g(h^{p^k})g^{-1}=1$$so $ghg^{-1}\in H$.
> Can you do similarly for $K$?

Comment: this is assuming G is abelian right?

Comment: @Jack Why? If $G$ is abelian, then $H$ and $K$ (as defined) are subgroups; if they are subgroups (but $G$ abelian is not really necessary), then the argument works. But if $G$ is abelian, proving that subgroups are normal is easy, isn't it?

Comment: I only ask because how does $(ghg^{-1})^{p^k}=g(h^{p^k})g^{-1}$.

Comment: then for K we need to show $(gkg^{-1})^m=1.$ Then assuming the same process as above, we get $gk^mg^{-1}=1$. Hence K is normal

Comment: @Jack Just prove by induction that $(gxg^{-1})^n=gx^ng^{-1}$. It becomes almost obvious if you realize that $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is a homomorphism of $G$ to itself.

Comment: nevermind I see that.

Comment: @Jack Definitely not.

Comment: but was I right about the K part?

Comment: @Jack Yes, of course: it's the same as for $H$, after all.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $G$ is generated by $H$ and $K$: there are $p^km$ ways to write a product $hk$ for $h\in H, k\in K$. If $h_1k_1=h_2k_2$, then $k_1k_2^{-1}=h_1^{-1}h_2$. Since this element is in both $H$ and $K$, it equals $1$, so $h_1=h_2$ and $k_1=k_2$. Thus, the $p^km$ products are distinct and thus give all of $G$.

Now, let $k'\in K$, $g\in G$. We seek to show that $g^{-1}kg\in K$, which will prove $K$ is normal. We can write $g=hk, h\in H, k\in K$, by the above reasoning. Then $g^{-1}k'g=k^{-1}h^{-1}k'hk$. Note that $(k^{-1}h^{-1}k'hk)^m=k^{-1}h^{-1}k'^mhk=k^{-1}h^{-1}1hk$, since $k'\in K\implies k'^m=1$. But $k^{-1}h^{-1}1hk=1$. We have thus shown that $(g^{-1}k'g)^m=1$, so this element is in $K$, as desired. Thus, $K$ is normal.

By the same argument as above, $H$ is also normal, and in fact, $G\cong H\times K$.

Comment: Is the first part sufficient to showing that for any $x\in G$ can be written as $hk$ with h in H and k in K?

Comment: Yes; after reading the other answer, I realized that it's not required to show that the groups are normal.

Comment: so if I were to say that since H and K are normal, then HK=KH generates G. therefore for any x in G, it can be written as a product hk=kh. or would I need more detail. we have not seen something like what you wrote, which is why I am just looking for a different way to say it that is simpler.

Comment: Yeah, you can delete the first part of my answer and just raise $g^{-1}k'g$ to the $m$th power, similar to the other answer.

Comment: However, my first part proves that $G=HK$, which in addition to $H\cap K=1$ and $H, K$ being normal is what you need to deduce that $G\cong H\times K$.